# Schedule tasks via PHP

Tags: php, cron, task, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to create and schedule a task from within a php app?
I want to give my users the option to schedule and run the script at a time of their choosing without them getting into cron jobs or windows task scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give your users access to a "cron" table that mimics the options that cron offers. There they can store the jobs the need to execute.

Then you can run a cron job every minute that checks that table to see if there are entries / jobs that need to be processed.